# Pandas TimeGrouper: .median() behaves differently to .quantile(0.5)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a multi-year time series and want to find quantiles by season.

Numerically, this works fine. However, I'm getting a `MultiIndex` `Series` as output when I expect a singly-indexed `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01', end='2016-01-01', freq='30T')
a_data = np.random.normal(loc=np.pi, scale=np.e, size=len(rng))
b_data = a_data - 5
df = pd.DataFrame(index=rng, data={'a': a_data, 'b': b_data})    
grouped = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='QS-DEC'))  
mult_idx_series = grouped.quantile(0.5)
mult_idx_series
```

shows a `MultiIndex`'d `Series`:

```
2013-12-01  a    3.079999
            b   -1.920001
2014-03-01  a    3.126490
            b   -1.873510
```

I'd expected (and wanted) the same ouput format as .median()

```
median_df = grouped.median()
median_df
```

which looks like:

```
            a         b
2013-12-01  3.079999 -1.920001
2014-03-01  3.126490 -1.873510
```

I should point out that:

- it isn't the 0.5th quantile that I want in reality
- I know I'm only `mult_idx_series.unstack(1)` from the format I want

I was surprised by the different return shapes and want to understand the reasoning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference lies in the fact that `grouped.median()` calls an optimized (cythonized) `median` aggregation function, while `grouped.quantile()` calls a generic wrapper to *apply* the function on the groups.

Consider this:

```
In [56]: grouped.apply(lambda x: x.quantile(0.5))
Out[56]:
2013-12-01  a    3.175594
            b   -1.824406
2014-03-01  a    3.116556
            b   -1.883444
2014-06-01  a    3.222320
            b   -1.777680
2014-09-01  a    3.207015
            b   -1.792985
2014-12-01  a    3.114767
            b   -1.885233
2015-03-01  a    3.091952
            b   -1.908048
2015-06-01  a    3.220528
            b   -1.779472
2015-09-01  a    3.204990
            b   -1.795010
2015-12-01  a    3.108755
            b   -1.891245
dtype: float64

In [57]: grouped.agg(lambda x: x.quantile(0.5))
Out[57]:
                   a         b
2013-12-01  3.175594 -1.824406
2014-03-01  3.116556 -1.883444
2014-06-01  3.222320 -1.777680
2014-09-01  3.207015 -1.792985
2014-12-01  3.114767 -1.885233
2015-03-01  3.091952 -1.908048
2015-06-01  3.220528 -1.779472
2015-09-01  3.204990 -1.795010
2015-12-01  3.108755 -1.891245
```

So `grouped.quantile()` does a general *apply* and not an *aggregation*. The reason for this is that `quantile` can also return a DataFrame (and thus is not always a pure aggregation), if you calculate multiple quantiles at once, eg with `grouped.quantile([0.1, 0.5, 0.9])`:

```
In [67]: grouped.quantile([0.1, 0.5, 0.9])
Out[67]:
                       a         b
2013-12-01 0.1 -0.310566 -5.310566
           0.5  3.131418 -1.868582
           0.9  6.624399  1.624399
2014-03-01 0.1 -0.219992 -5.219992
           0.5  3.173881 -1.826119
           0.9  6.550259  1.550259
...
```

Comment: Can we actually calculate multiple quantiles with a single call? Doing `grouped.quantile([0.1, 0.5, 0.9])` gives me `TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'", u'occurred at index a')` from `scipy.scoreatpercentile()` via `pandas.core.frame.quantile()`

Comment: What version of pandas do you have? It works for me (0.14.1). See output in answer

Comment: ah, that will be it.  I'm still only on `0.13.1`. Thanks