# why quantile(0.5) and median output different result when I use groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, median, quantile

I use `groupby` function and followed by median, but the result is different when I change median to quantile(0.5) why?

```
df.groupby(['PUMA', 'R65'])['HINCP'].quantile(0.5)

df.groupby(['PUMA', 'R65'])['HINCP'].median()
```

The above should be the same right？

[image: check the screenshot]

FYI. The dataset is here: https://github.com/kihyukh/stats206/raw/master/data/pums_short.csv.gz

And my pandas version is 1.0.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas TimeGrouper: .median() behaves differently to .quantile(0.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551388/pandas-timegrouper-median-behaves-differently-to-quantile0-5)

Comment: No. The numeric results are different, not the format. For example, the last line, 74000 vs 74500.